# ActionContext in IActionContextAccessor registered through DI is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm having some issue with `IActionContextAccessor` using asp.net core's builtin DI container. The `IActionContextAccessor.ActionContext` property is null on every request. I'm trying to register `IActionContextAccessor` like this:

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>( );
services.TryAddScoped<ITenantProvider, TenantProvider>( );
```

And I'm trying to access the `ActionContextAccessor.ActionContext` here

```
public TenantProvider( SomeTenantsDbContext context, IActionContextAccessor accessor )
{
    var alias = accessor?.ActionContext?.RouteData?.Values["tenant"]?.ToString();
    if(alias != null)
    {
        _tenantId = context.Tenants.FirstOrDefault( t => t.Alias == alias )?.Id;
    }
}
```

What could be the cause for this. All suggestions are welcome

Comment: Where and how are you using the `TenantProvider`? And are you sure the `ActionContext` is actually null? You are chaining a lot of null conditional operators there.

Comment: Yes `ActionContext ` is actually null. I'm using it in the following order `Controller` -> `Service` -> `UoW` -> `DbContext`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you are using the `IActionContextAccessor.ActionContext` in the constructor of the `TenantProvider`. This usually leads to problems you are experiencing due to the fact that the `TenantProvider` might be instantiated when the `IActionContextAccessor.ActionContext` is not yet set to the action currently executing.

I suggest you move the logic in your constructor to some method of `TentantProvider` and call that from the controller. For example:

```
private readonly SomeTenantsDbContext _context;
privat readonly IActionContextAccessor _accessor;

public TenantProvider(SomeTenantsDbContext context, IActionContextAccessor accessor )
{
    _context = context;
    _accessor = accessor;
}

public void DoStuuff()
{    
    var alias = _accessor?.ActionContext?.RouteData?.Values["tenant"]?.ToString();
    if(alias != null)
    {
        var tenantId = _context.Tenants.FirstOrDefault( t => t.Alias == alias)?.Id;
        // Do something with tenant id
    }
}
```